# Whats the algorithm that Array#include? uses?

Tags: ruby, arrays

For ruby where `x` is an array, how does `x.include?(y)` check if `y` is in `x`? What's the algorithm?

Comment: you can find the source of the function http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-include-3F

Comment: It's `O(n)`. For `O(1)`, use a `Set` instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the array does not have to be sorted, the algorithm cannot be anything better than "look at each element and see if it matches".

Comment: @cfarm54 With a large sorted array a binary search would be faster in most cases. http://0xcc.net/ruby-bsearch/index.html.en

Comment: yep, and i assume there are no functions for this in ruby

Comment: @cfarm54 There are several. In fact I linked to one in my previous comment.

Comment: As @Marc-AndréLafortune mentioned, the Ruby builtin `Set` is even better, as its members are stored as a Hash internally.

Answer (score 6):

As an addition to Greg Hewgill's answer, the source code from Ruby 1.9.3 for this method is:

```
VALUE
rb_ary_includes(VALUE ary, VALUE item)
{
    long i;

    for (i=0; i<RARRAY_LEN(ary); i++) {
        if (rb_equal(RARRAY_PTR(ary)[i], item)) {
            return Qtrue;
        }
    }
    return Qfalse;
}
```

Thus, as Greg has said, the algorithm is just a linear search through the array.